# Valgrind reporting invalid write errors

Tags: c, valgrind

This is more focused than my previous Valgrind question; I am trying to narrow down write and read errors when parsing command-line options:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <sys/utsname.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#include <sys/stat.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
#include <string.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <locale.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <bzlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#include <zlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#include "starch.h"

#define BUFMAXLEN 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (parseCommandLineInputs( &argc, &argv ) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return 0;
} 

int parseCommandLineInputs(int *argc, char ***argv) {

    pid_t pid;                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    struct utsname uts;
    char uniqTag[BUFMAXLEN];

    if ((*argc == 1) || (*argc > 4)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                
        printUsage();
        return -1;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    if ((pid = getpid()) < 0) {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\t[starch] - Error: Could not obtain process ID\n\n");                                                                                                                                                     
        return -1;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    uname( &uts );                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    sprintf(uniqTag, "pid%d.%s", pid, uts.nodename);                                                                                                                                                                                  

    switch (*argc) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        case 2: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            if (strcmp(*argv[1], "-") != 0) {                                                                                                                                                                                         
                if (fileExists(*argv[1]) != 0) { /* standard input */                                                                                                                                                              
                    ...
    }

    return 0;
}


int fileExists(char *fn) {
    struct stat buf;
    int i = stat (fn, &buf);
    if (i == 0)
        return 0;
    return -1;
}

void printUsage() {
    fprintf(stderr, "my usage statement\n\n");
}
```

My makefile is as follows:

```
CC      = gcc                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
CFLAGS  = -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DUSE_ZLIB -O3 -Wformat -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -g                                                                                                                        
BIN     = ../bin                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

all: starch                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    rm -rf *~                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

starch: starch.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    mkdir -p $(BIN) && $(CC) ${CFLAGS} starch.o -lbz2 -lz -o ${BIN}/starch                                                                                                                                                            
    rm -rf *~                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ ${BIN}/starch
```

I get the following errors when I run with `valgrind`:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes -v ../bin/starch

...

==2675== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
==2675== Invalid read of size 8                                                                                                                                                                                                       
==2675==    at 0x3AB4262243: fwrite (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)                                                                                                                                                                           
==2675==  Address 0x7fedffd68 is on thread 1's stack                                                                                                                                                                                  
==2675==                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
==2675==                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
==2675== 1 errors in context 2 of 2:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
==2675== Invalid write of size 8                                                                                                                                                                                                      
==2675==    at 0x401AA6: parseCommandLineInputs (starch.c:217)                                                                                                                                                                        
==2675==    by 0x7FF0000AF: ???                                                                                                                                                                                                       
==2675==    by 0x401DFA: main (starch.c:46)                                                                                                                                                                                           
==2675==  Address 0x7fedffd68 is on thread 1's stack
```

The first error is not telling me anything I can use, since I am not using `fwrite()` anywhere.

The second error is tripped up on the `fprintf` statement in `printUsage()`.

Line 46 is the following line:

```
 if (parseCommandLineInputs( &argc, &argv ) != 0)
```

Line 217 is the following line:

```
 fprintf(stderr, "my usage statement\n\n");
```

What is wrong with my application that explains why these errors appear?

Comment: This isn't the complete program (no `#include`s, no definition for `uts`, `uniqTag`, or `pid`). Why are the lines in `parseCommandLineInputs` full of trailing space?

Comment: How do you expect us to debug your program with only half the information ? where is uts, uniqTag ? what is the line 46 and 217 of starch.c ? have you tried using --db-attach=yes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things that pop up to me right away:

- *argv[1] is NOT the same as (*argv)[1] which is what you probably mean. Array subscripting has precedence over pointer dereferencing. This results in an invalid pointer. As many experienced programmers will tell you: "Don't try to remember the precedence of operators - if in doubt use parentheses, if not just use them anyway".
- -O3 in the compiler flags is a big fat NO-NO when debugging. The compiler will mangle your code so much that it can make your life impossible. Variables can disappear completely and functions can go mysteriously away as they get inlined. If your code compiles, links and runs with -O0 (IIRC some code containing inline assembly needs -O1 with some (all?) GCC versions) use it, otherwise use -O1 at most.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up replacing `malloc/sprintf` statements with `strdup` statements. For whatever reason, this fixed the valgrind error messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is too much missing so it is not easy to tell what is going on. I suppose that `pid` is `pid_t`?
The only thing that I then see is this one:

```
sprintf(uniqTag, "pid%d.%s", pid, uts.nodename);
```

`pid_t` is not necessarily an `int` so `sprintf` might be on the wrong track when parsing its arguments and messup your stack. But `gcc` should have have told you if you compile with `-Wall`, which I suppose.

Try compiling with a different compiler, clang e.g.